# Using "for example" as a parenthesis

Tags: grammar, parenthesis

Where should "for example" be? Both "yoga class" and "basketball" are examples. How can I use "for example" to modify both "yoga class" and "basketball"? Or should I actually modify "show up for a yoga class" and "play basketball"?

> China now has a "996" work culture. This means that many of us wouldn't be
> able to show up for, **for example**, a yoga class that starts at 7 p.m.
> on weekdays or play basketball with friends on Sundays.

> China now has a "996" work culture. This means that many of us wouldn't be
> able to, **for example**, show up for a yoga class that starts at 7 p.m.
> on weekdays or play basketball with friends on Sundays.

Comment: In the first sentence you can use "as example", "as examples", "as an example"(this may not do as you have provided two examples, but in spoken you can get away with it)

Comment: Thank you very much. What's wrong with "for example"?

Comment: The phrase seems almost unnecessary. What else would the reader think they are except examples?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But I want to learn where I should add "for example" in my sentence. Could you tell me?

Comment: I don't like your first version because of the two 'fors'. Personally, I would go for _wouldn't be able, for example, to show up... or to play basketball..._ - but this is opinion-based.